# jQuery: Can't change the select option. Tried all the solutions I can find

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have an html select with id 'project-entry-form--category'
The html for the options (not the select element itself) for which are pulled via AJAX.

With that select, I can `console.log($('#project-entry-form--category'))` and get back everything jQuery knows about it. It shows the options. So, I know jQuery can "see" them and therefore should be able to set the selected prop on them.
I can also `console.log($proj_data.cat_id)` and get back the desired value for the category.
It seems like I have all the pieces, but it just doesn't do anything.

I have tried

```
$('#project-entry-form--category').val($proj_data.cat_id);
```

and

```
$('#project-entry-form--category option[value="'+$proj_data.cat_id+'"]').prop('selected', 'selected').change();
```

and

```
$('#project-entry-form--category option[value="'+$proj_data.cat_id+'"]').prop('selected', true);
```

None of which work.

If I try `console.log($('#project-entry-form--category').val());` I get null. So it would seem jQuery doesn't see an initial value for the select. I assume just because the select shows the first option, but it isn't "selected."

If I do this:

```
$('#project-entry-form--category').change( function () {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
```

I do get the values in the console when I change it. So, again, jQuery can "see" the option values at the point I am trying to set the value. And it also indicates I am spelling the selector correctly, so no typo fouling things up.

I am stumped! Any help is appreciated!

--EDIT--

It was requested I do a snippet of what I'm trying. Seems I have an issue with the AJAX options getting there in time for the .val() to change it.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
var $select_html = 
  '<option value="1" data-fold="Commercial">Commercial</option>'+
  '<option value="3" data-fold="Ecclesiastical">Ecclesiastical</option>'+
  '<option value="2" data-fold="Institutional - Educational">Institutional / Educational</option>'+
  '<option value="4" data-fold="Municipal">Municipal</option>'+
  '<option value="5" data-fold="Residential">Residential</option>'+
  '<option value="6" data-fold="Secure Projects">Secure</option>';
  $('#project-entry-form--category').html($select_html);
}, 500);
// Category ID received via AJAX - console.log() reveals the value is 5 (Residential)
var $proj_data = {'cat_id':5};
var $base = 'project-entry';
$('#' + $base + '-form--category').val($proj_data.cat_id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-select" id="project-entry-form--category" name="project-entry-form--category"></select>
```

Comment: `$('#project-entry-form--category').val($proj_data.cat_id);` (your first attempt) is the correct way to do it, and **will** work if `$proj_data.cat_id` is an exact match for one of the `select` element's option's value and the `select` element is in the document at the point you make that call. If you can't get it working, please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: I can console.log() the cat_id and it shows 5 in this case. One of the select options says value="5". It definitely should match.
Hard to provide a runnable example when I have an AJAX call involved to get the select options. I guess I can show everything I'm trying after the select options are generated.

Comment: See the [second link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/) for suggestions about ajax stuff. For instance, use `setTimeout` and hardcoded data for the ajax result. Also see the first link for why going through the process of building a [mcve] is useful in any case (basically: nine times out of ten, you find the problem). Good luck!

Comment: this must have to do with the order of operations. Can you show the sequence that loads the select menu up with options and then tries to select one of them?

Comment: Yeah, as fast as it is, maybe the options aren't populated yet when I'm trying to set them. I may have to alter my code to get the back-end to pre-select the correct option when I ask for it when populating a form for editing.

Comment: Sure enough. Adding the setTimeout() reveals that it's an AJAX timing issue.

Comment: I don‘t think you should let the backend pre-select anything that entierly depends on a user input. If it does not, then sure, but why the hassle with a select input and not a disabled text input (and some form of verification, but you need that anyway). Can you add the AJAX call and the order of execution to your snippet? I think too, that you want to work with the result before it is available (see jquery.ajax.done or jquery.ajax.statusCode if you return one)

Comment: I'm thinking one way of solving this would be to have the back-end pre-select the option ONLY when the project is retrieved for an edit operation. So, the select options would pop in with the option assigned to the project selected. The user could still change the option and then save the project again. I simulated the AJAX call with the timeout. Otherwise, in that limited example, that is the order of execution.

Comment: So, what I ended up doing was change my function that makes the AJAX call to accept an arg "preselect". So, when the AJAX comes back, if there's a pre-select set, then it sets that option to be selected. Works good and waits for the AJAX as I should. Thanks for the input guys!

Answer (score 0):

So, because it became obvious the options weren't in the DOM in time for the `$('#project-entry-form--category').val($proj_data.cat_id);` to set it, I added a param `$pre_select` to my `ajax_get_select_options()` function to optionally set the value of the select after it comes back. Same function can be used without pre-select for a default option set.

```js
function ajax_get_select_options($pre_select) { // Added the $pre_select param
  setTimeout(() => { // Mimic AJAX timing
  
  var $select_html = // HTML received from back-end API
    '<option value="1" data-fold="Commercial">Commercial</option>'+
    '<option value="3" data-fold="Ecclesiastical">Ecclesiastical</option>'+
    '<option value="2" data-fold="Institutional - Educational">Institutional / Educational</option>'+
    '<option value="4" data-fold="Municipal">Municipal</option>'+
    '<option value="5" data-fold="Residential">Residential</option>'+
    '<option value="6" data-fold="Secure Projects">Secure</option>';
    
    // The following happens inside the success block of the ajax call...
    
    // Add the options into the select element
    $('#project-entry-form--category').html($select_html); 
    
    // Add the ability to set the value of the select
    if ($pre_select) {
      // Need to add a check here to make sure $pre_select value exists
      // in the options value set before trying to set it
      $('#project-entry-form--category').val($pre_select);
    }
    
  }, 500);
}

// Category ID received via separate AJAX API call along with other $project data
var $proj_data = {'cat_id':5};

// Call for the options and specify a value to pre-select
ajax_get_select_options($proj_data.cat_id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-select" id="project-entry-form--category" name="project-entry-form--category"></select>
```